# CefSharp's Minimal Example and Multi-Threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I tried to implement the minimal example in my application. In this application I call the Marketing-Windows (i.e. the ChromiumWebBrowser) the following way:
My App.xaml.cs looks this way:

```
namespace ASA_Videowand
{
    public partial class App
    {
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            // ...
                foreach (List<string> myStrings in Screen.AllScreens.Select(myScreen => _xml.GetScreenConfigs(i)))
                {
                     // ...
                            int i1 = i;
                            List<string> strings = myStrings;
                            var newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                var myMarketing = new Marketing(i1, strings[0]);
                                myMarketing.Show();
                                Dispatcher.Run();
                            });
                            newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                            newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
                            newWindowThread.Start();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Marketing.xaml and Marketing.xaml.cs:

```
<Window x:Class="ASA_Videowand.Marketing"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:main="clr-namespace:ASA_Videowand.Views"
        Title="{Binding WebBrowser.Title}">
    <Grid>
        <main:MainView />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and

```
namespace ASA_Videowand
{
    public partial class Marketing
    {
        public Marketing(int screenNumber, string myLink)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here comes my MainView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ASA_Videowand.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignWidth="640"
             d:DesignHeight="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0"
                                     Address="http://www.google.com"
                                     WebBrowser="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                     Title="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <StatusBar Grid.Row="1">
            <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                         IsIndeterminate="{Binding WebBrowser.IsLoading}"
                         Width="100"
                         Height="16"
                         Margin="3" />
            <Separator />
            <!-- TODO: Could show hover link URL here -->
            <TextBlock />
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and my MainView.xaml.cs:

```
namespace ASA_Videowand.Views
{
    public partial class MainView : UserControl
    {
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

And before it goes on, it stops in the MainView.xaml with the exeption, that

```
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0"
                                     Address="http://www.google.com"
                                     WebBrowser="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                     Title="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

would belong to another thread and therefore cannot be modified.
I am new to multi-Threading. If I try it with the build-in IE-WebControl it works fine this way. I know how I can call something from the code-behind, but getting this exception in a View is new to me.
How can I make this work? I appreciate any idea. Thanks.

Comment: Could you place the exact error as well?

Comment: *How can I make this work?*... simple... don't do UI work on a background thread.

Comment: In german its: {"Der aufrufende Thread kann nicht auf dieses Objekt zugreifen, da sich das Objekt im Besitz eines anderen Threads befindet."} The english translation should be something like: "The calling thread cannot access this object, because the object is owned by another thread."

Comment: yeah, but the threadingerror is caused in the creation of the window. i only want to call the windows in their own thread. but how should i do this? Never had used views and multithreading together.

Comment: and for the love of god, use tasks

Answer (score 2):

Put quite simply:

> You cannot do UI work on a background thread

Just use the UI thread to do your UI work instead:

```
foreach (List<string> myStrings in Screen.AllScreens.Select(myScreen => _xml.GetScreenConfigs(i)))
{
     // ...
            int i1 = i;
            List<string> strings = myStrings;
            var myMarketing = new Marketing(i1, strings[0]);
            myMarketing.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: When I call this window 12 times (yeah, it runs on a server with 16 screens altogether), and initiate in every window via XAML a ChromiumWebBrowser, all 12 run in one thread and the server goes down onto his knees. I need to run the WebBrowsers in different threads. So you say, I cannot use XAML to initialize them? that will be hard to transfer into my app. Whats interesting is, that when I use this kind of tasks, and dont use views, but a simple WebBrowser (the one based on IE), everything works fine.

Comment: I didn't say that you can't use XAML, I said that you can't run UI code on a background thread. If your control has no UI related code, then you *can* run it on a background thread, but there's got to be a better solution than running a dozen UI controls that you don't want to see in the UI.